# Given the information, what is the probability that the mean number of drinks sold per week is between 700 and 720

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval

The question .

[image: a busy cat]

I'm kinda a bit confused on how to make use of the information to answer the questions. I think I need to use the Bayesian Method to answer this question but I'm not sure if I'm right.

would the prior density of the mean be $\mathcal{N}(738,13.4^2)$? Then what do I do with the $\mathcal{N}(692,42.5^2)$ Given in the second half of the question?

I'm really clueless in using the Bayesian method and would like some guidance in understanding this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In a *particular* market, $\sigma=42.5$. If we *assume normality*, then $drinks\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,42.5^2)$.
2. What about $\mu$? The overall mean is centered around $\mu_0=738$ and its variability is $\sigma_0=13.4$. So, if we *assume normality*, a *prior* for $\mu$ is $\mu\sim \mathcal{N}(738,13.4^2)$.
3. As to a new market during the first $n=10$ weeks, you don't know $\mu$ but know the sample mean $\bar{x}=692$ and the variance $\sigma^2=42.5^2$. So you can use a normal-normal model with known variance. The posterior for the mean is normal and its mean and variance are (see [here](http://www.bcs.rochester.edu/people/robbie/jacobslab/cheat_sheet/bayes_Normal_Normal.pdf)):
   $$\hat\mu=\frac{\sigma^2\mu_0+n\sigma^2_0\bar{x}}{\sigma^2+n\sigma^2_0}=\frac{42.5^2\cdot738+10\cdot13.4^2\cdot692}{42.5^2+10\cdot13.4^2}$$
   $$\hat\sigma^2=\frac{\sigma^2_0\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+n\sigma^2_0}=\frac{13.4^2\cdot42.5^2}{42.5^2+10\cdot 13.4^2}$$
   You can use $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\hat\mu,\hat\sigma^2)$ to compute $P(700<X<720)$.

What does that mean? The distributor expect a mean about 738, but observes $\bar{x}=692$ during the first 10 weeks. He doesn't believe that it is a definitive result. So he *weighs* his observation and his past experience. Indeed $\hat\mu$ depends on both the prior mean (past experience) and the sample mean (what he has observed). His estimate of the average number of drinks sold in the new market will be updated by future observations, i.e. as $n$ grows. You can see that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\hat\mu=\bar{x}$$
For now, ten weeks is a short time, so he builds his belief on both $\bar{x}$ and $\mu_0$.

This is called *shrinkage estimation*: the estimation of $\mu$ is *shrunken* toward the prior mean when $n$ is small.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I kinda managed to derive the posterior density of a normal distribution before. I just had some trouble trying to plug in the info.

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble trying to compute P(700<X<720). I either keept getting a too big of a number or a negative answer. I tried integrating the posterior density from 700 to 720, but I still can't seem to get it.

Comment: My answer was -0.742.

Comment: $X\sim\mathcal{N}(715.068,9.489229^2)$. Using R:  
`> mu <- (42.5^2*738+10*13.4^2*692)/(42.5^2+10*13.4^2)
; sigma <- sqrt(13.4^2*42.5^2/(42.5^2+10*13.4^2))
; pnorm(720,mu,sigma)-pnorm(700,mu,sigma)
[1] 0.6422261`  


Otherwise, using a standard normal table:
$$\begin{split}P(700<X<720)&=P(X<720)-P(X<700)\\&= P\left(Z<\frac{720-715.068}{9.489229}\right)-P\left(Z<\frac{700-715.068}{9.489229}\right)\\&\approx P(Z<0.52)-P(Z<-1.59)\approx 0.6426\end{split}$$

Comment: Oh my god I feel like an absolute idiot after seeing this. I'm so sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: No problem. You're welcome.